# How to convert pandas column to date when column is something like "Jan-18"?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

what is the efficient way to convert the column values into dates "DD-MM-YYYY" when the values given like "Feb-15" which needs to be "01-02-2015". if it's "Dec-46" it must return "01-12-1946".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the format `'%b-%y'` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
In[42]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["Feb-15","Dec-46"]})
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')
df

Out[42]: 
     date   new_date
0  Feb-15 2015-02-01
1  Dec-46 2046-12-01
```

Note that the new `dtype` is `datetime64`, you cannot control the display output, if you insist on `DD-MM-YYYY` then you would have to convert to a string using [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas.Series.dt.strftime):

```
In[43]:
df['str_date'] = df['new_date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df

Out[43]: 
     date   new_date    str_date
0  Feb-15 2015-02-01  01-02-2015
1  Dec-46 2046-12-01  01-12-2046
```

but then you have strings which is not that useful if you need to perform arithmetic operations or filtering

**EDIT**

You cannot store dates earlier than 1970 so `'01-01-1946'` is not a valid datetime that can be represented by `datetime64`

Comment: Dec-46 should be 1946 since it's historical data. That's the issue otherwise it's very straight fwd.

Comment: You'd have to subtract 100 years from that entry I will update